# Autosave has stopped functioning 2.91

Tags: blend-files

Autosave worked fine. At some point today, it stopped saving files.

All settings in preferences are as they should be. I have installed no new add-ons today. I have changed nothing in settings.

However, now autosave does not autosave. I tried changing the directory, no effect. No autosave.

Version 2.91. This is not the first time this has happened to me, I would also mention. I fixed it last time... by buying a new computer. I would prefer not to have to do that again.

Comment: Hello, this is unusal, are you sure you have the rights to write files in the temp folder ?

Comment: @gorgious I have permission for the temp folder, but regardless, it is not saving there or the folder I specified as the new destination.